# How can the sender be saved in an outlook mail template

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have some mail templates I & my colleagues frequently use in Outlook 2010,  which need to be sent from a shared mailbox. Every time I send one, I need to first change the 'From' address (like this: [image: From address selection]), which takes time and can be overlooked.

Is there a way (macro or otherwise) to save the from address as part of the mail template (.oft), so it does not have to be set every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some trial and error, but here's the macro:

```vb
Sub templateName()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\templateName.oft")

    With objMsg
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "desiredname@email.com"
        .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in option in Outlook to save the From field in an template. As per macro, I found [a similar discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/341520-save-from-sender-in-outlook-template) in another forum but the macro mentioned there didn't work for me.